# Exibindo mensagem de nenhum número lido e aceitando diferentes tipos de entrada

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
def maior(colecao):
    if len(colecao) > 1:
        r = maior(colecao[1:])
        if r[0] < colecao[0]:
            r[0] = colecao[0]
    elif len(colecao) == 1:
        r = [colecao[0]]
    else:
        r = [None]
    return r


def imprimir(colecao):
    if len(colecao) != 0:
        print("Maior Valor Encontrado:", colecao[0])
    else:
        print("nenhum número foi lido!!!")


valores = input().split()
for i in range(len(valores)):
    valores[i] = float(valores[i])

imprimir(maior(valores))
```

Quando eu digito valores, como por exemplo: 1, 10, 50, 5, ele tem a saída certinho:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando não digito nenhum valor e dou <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, ele não informa que nenhum número foi lido, e tem essa saída:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ele exibisse a mensagem correta quando nenhum número for lido         ("nenhum número foi lido!!!") e também que, além dele aceitar entrada 1, 10, 50, 5 aceitasse também entrada:

```
1 
10
50
5
```

E não estou sabendo implementar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que `maior` está retornando uma lista ao invés de um só elemento. E então, basta  função `imprimir` testar pelo `None`.

```
def maior(colecao):
    if len(colecao) == 0:
        return None
    if len(colecao) == 1:
        return colecao[0]
    r = maior(colecao[1:])
    if r < colecao[0]:
        r = colecao[0]
    return r

def imprimir(e):
    if e is None:
        print("nenhum número foi lido!!!")
    else:
        print("Maior Valor Encontrado:", e)

valores = input().split()
for i in range(len(valores)):
    valores[i] = float(valores[i])

imprimir(maior(valores))
```

Se por algum motivo você quiser insistir de que `maior` deve retornar uma lista, basta trocar o `[None]` por `[]`:

```
def maior(colecao):
    if len(colecao) > 1:
        r = maior(colecao[1:])
        if r[0] < colecao[0]:
            r[0] = colecao[0]
    elif len(colecao) == 1:
        r = [colecao[0]]
    else:
        r = []
    return r


def imprimir(colecao):
    if len(colecao) != 0:
        print("Maior Valor Encontrado:", colecao[0])
    else:
        print("nenhum número foi lido!!!")


valores = input().split()
for i in range(len(valores)):
    valores[i] = float(valores[i])

imprimir(maior(valores))
```

Se bem que eu acho melhor que o código de `maior` fosse assim, por ser mais direto:

```
def maior(colecao):
    if len(colecao) == 0:
        return r
    if len(colecao) == 1:
        return [colecao[0]]
    r = maior(colecao[1:])
    if r[0] < colecao[0]:
        r[0] = colecao[0]
    return r
```

Answer (score 1):

Se você quer que a entrada aceite tanto os números na mesma linha quanto em linhas diferentes, uma opção é fazer um loop desta forma:

```
numeros = []
while True:
    valores = input().split();
    if not valores: # lista vazia, nenhum número foi digitado, encerrar a leitura
        break
    for s in valores:
        try:
            # tenta transformar em número
            numeros.append(float(s))
        except ValueError:
            pass # não é número, ignorar (ou pode imprimir uma mensagem, se quiser)
```

Quando o usuário digitar alguma coisa, eu faço o `split`. Se a lista resultante é vazia, quer dizer que ele não digitou nada (ou digitou somente espaços), e aí eu saio do loop com `break`.

Se algo foi digitado, eu percorro os valores e tento transformá-los em números. Caso o usuário digite algo que não é número (como `abc`, por exemplo), estou ignorando (mas você poderia imprimir uma mensagem, sair do loop e encerrar o programa, etc). Com isso a entrada pode ter várias linhas, e em cada linha podem ter um ou mais números.

---

Em seguida, para encontrar o maior número, não precisa usar uma função recursiva (a menos que seja um exercício que o professor pediu que seja recursivo, e neste caso pode se basear na [resposta do Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/403122/112052), que explica como corrigi-la). Em vez disso, você pode simplesmente fazer um loop simples:

```
def maior(numeros):
    r = numeros[0]
    for n in numeros:
        if n > r:
            r = n
    return r
```

Se bem que o loop acima tem uma redundância: eu começo inicializando `r` com o primeiro elemento da lista e depois percorro a lista toda, comparando cada elemento dela para saber qual o maior. Isso quer dizer que na primeira iteração estou comparando o primeiro elemento com ele mesmo, o que seria redundante. De qualquer forma, daria para começar o loop a partir do segundo elemento com `for i in range(1, len(numeros))`. E ela também poderia retornar `None` caso a lista seja vazia, como já foi sugerido na [resposta do Victor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/403122/112052).

Mas se isso não for um exercício que você precise implementar manualmente o algoritmo, bastaria usar a [função `max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

```
# encontrar o maior número da lista
maior = max(numeros)
```

Outro detalhe é que você está usando [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) para converter a string para número, o que dá a entender que o usuário vai poder digitar números como `1.5`, por exemplo. Mas se quiser somente números inteiros (sem casas decimais), bastaria trocar por [`int`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int).

---

Resumindo, o código poderia ficar assim:

```
numeros = []
while True:
    valores = input().split();
    if not valores: # lista vazia, nenhum número foi digitado, encerrar a leitura
        break
    for s in valores:
        try:
            # tenta transformar em número
            numeros.append(float(s))
        except ValueError:
            pass # não é número, ignorar

if numeros: # lista não é vazia
    print("Maior valor encontrado: {}".format(max(numeros)))
else: # lista vazia, nem tento encontrar o maior número
    print("Nenhum número foi lido")
```

Não tem porque o maior número ser retornado em uma lista que só tem um elemento, para depois você testar o tamanho desta lista. Basta verificar **antes** se a lista com todos os números é vazia (se for, então não tem porque tentar encontrar o maior valor, e já cai direto no `else`).

---

No exemplo acima eu usei a função `max` para encontrar o maior número. Mas se quiser muito usar sua própria função para encontrar o maior, e também a função que imprime o número, ficaria assim:

```
numeros = []
while True:
    ... igual ao código anterior

def maior(numeros):
    if not numeros: # lista vazia, retornar None
        return None
    r = numeros[0]
    for n in numeros:
        if n > r:
            r = n
    return r

def imprimir(n):
    if n is None:
        print("Nenhum número foi lido")
    else:
        print("Maior valor encontrado: {}".format(n))

imprimir(maior(numeros))
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, coloque o que voce deseja 'splitar' dentro da funcao split():
Mude

```
    valores = input().split()
```

para

```
    valores = input().split(',')
```

Depois, faça um *if* para o caso em que o input venha vazio:

```
    if valores == ['']:
    print("Nenhum valor lido")
    return
```

O código ficara mais ou menos assim:

```
def maior(colecao):
    if len(colecao) > 1:
        r = maior(colecao[1:])
        if r[0] < colecao[0]:
            r[0] = colecao[0]
    elif len(colecao) == 1:
        r = [colecao[0]]
    else:
        r = [None]
    return r


def imprimir(colecao):
    if len(colecao) != 0:
        print("Maior Valor Encontrado:", colecao[0])
    else:
        print("nenhum numero foi lido!!!")


valores = input("Digite o valor").split(',')
if valores == ['']:
    print("Nenhum valor lido")
    return
for i in range(len(valores)):
    valores[i] = float(valores[i])

imprimir(maior(valores))
```